# Custom Annotations for Spring Boot Tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing

Is it possible to overwrite the parameter values of an annotation used in a custom annotation?

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@SpringBootTest(classes = [HOW_TO_CHANGE_THESE])
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {[HOW_TO_CHANGE_THESE]})
@ActiveProfiles("testing")
public @interface IntegrationTest {
}
```

My intention was to reduce the number of annotations in my tests, while setting default values to all tests of this type. I would like to use it like this:

```
@IntegrationTest(classes="...", basePackages="...")
class AbcTest {
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible if you are using the Spring framework. It has a special [@AliasFor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AliasFor.html) annotation for this purpose:

> @AliasFor is an annotation that is used to declare aliases for annotation attributes.

You can find more examples of its usage in the official documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-meta-annotations) or in [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aliasfor-annotation).

Also, there are details of how to use meta-annotations in the Spring Test Context in the official documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations-meta).

Your example with the usage of this annotation will look like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@SpringBootTest
@ComponentScan
@ActiveProfiles("testing")
public @interface IntegrationTest {

    @AliasFor(annotation = ComponentScan.class, attribute = "basePackages")
    String[] basePackages() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = SpringBootTest.class, attribute = "classes")
    Class<?>[] classes() default {};
}
```